# Observables vs Promises for Single Synchronous Request/Response

Tags: angular, http, promise, observable

I need to make a choice between RxJs Observables and Promises, so here are my questions:

1. Is it worths using an **Observable** instead of a **Promise** for single synchronous request/response with 1 value?
2. If it worths, what would be the benefits of using Observables over Promises for this case?

Comment: Observables are useful when doing [reactive programming](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/what-is-reactive-programming-da37c1611382)

Answer (score 3):

> It worths using an Observable instead of a Promise for single synchronous request/response with 1 value?

Yes.

> If it worths, what would be the benefits of using Observables over Promises for this case?

You have access to the huge set of operators that can be applied to observables:

- if there is an error, you might want to retry the request
- if the response takes too much time to come back, you might want to cancel it
- if you need to call multiple services, you can combine them in various ways with switchMap, combineLatest, forkJoin, etc.
- etc.

Observables are an integral part of Angular. They're hard to grasp (harder than promises), but you need to understand them to fully use the framework. So I would not try to avoid them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how about the management cost of subscribing and unsubscribing from Observables?

Comment: What do you mean by "management cost"? You generally don't have to unsubscribe from a single-event observable. And calling subscribe() vs. calling then() doesn't make much of a difference, does it?

Comment: Uhmm, then I was confused. Why I haven't to unsubscribe from a single event? -- I don't want the observable remains active after push the data to the observers on a single-event.

Comment: As soon as an observable completes (or errors), all the observers are automatically unsubscribed. And a single-event observable completes immediately after it has emitted its unique event.